# How send data to OTRS from external service

Tags: otrs

I want send email from page "Create New Email Ticket (?Action=AgentTicketEmail)" in OTRS system. But I want do this from external service. I think, i should use OTRS API, but i can not simple example for this task.

How use OTRS API ?

Comment: So you wan't to create a ticket in OTRS via an external service or from OTRS within an external service? Which OTRS version are you using ? regards

Comment: Hello. I use OTRS 5. 
I want use my own service for creating ticket in OTRS system. I found this OTRS API https://otrs.github.io/doc/api/otrs/stable/Perl/index.html, but i don`t understood how use it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read up on using Web Services with OTRS -> http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/genericinterface.html#genericinterface-connectors

**! Updated Link for Ver. 6:**

https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/6.0/en/html/genericinterface.html

You'll need the other application to create a ticket via the web service interface, using SOAP or REST.
The linked documentation has examples in Perl and also examples how to create the REST request using `curl` on the command line.